# How do you write code to allow other client websites to authenticate via your web service?

Tags: java, web-services, popup

www.hbogo.com
Click on "Sign In" and select your provider.
Click on Verizon FIOS
You see a popup from verizon show up to allow you to enter your Verizon username and password.

https://www.kickstarter.com/login
Click on "Login with Facebook"

and there are tons of more examples.

Notice in the above examples you see a popup served from the authenticating domain (in the first case you see a Verizon popup and in the second case you see a Facebook popup).  Clearly Verizon FIOS and Facebook have written code (a web service?) that allows client websites (like HBOGO.com and Kickstarter.com) to easily authenticate.

I want to create a web service similar to what Verison FIOS or Facebook and I was wondering if there is any sample code I could follow that would help me get started? The goal would be to have other clients authenticate with my webservice (just like HBOGO and KickStarter authenticate through Verizon FIOS and Facebook respectively).

Comment: Those systems work because there are already so many users employing the original website.  Facebook only opened its authentication platform after it had a global reputation.  Without that, there will be no one to even benefit from your new proprietary platform

Comment: You basically need a secure method for other websites to ask you "is this username/password combo correct?" They need to trust you well enough to entrust you with some sort of login token that you can use to verify (and, frankly, as @DarkNinja955 says, they need to *want* to ask you--this is the first thing you should consider, will my hard work get used?). Do some web-searching for "OAuth"; that's one mechanism you might use.

Comment: How about OAuth 2.0? I believe that's what they used. There should be a lot of tutorials on how to set up an authentication server.